# Spring Integration and Rabbit MQ: Aggregation of multiple jobs

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, rabbitmq, spring-integration

I have a spring integration flow, where one consumer picks up a job from Rabbit MQ, and splits it up into multiple smaller jobs that get queued back to Rabbit MQ that get picked up by other consumers on different servers. Is there good way to aggregate the smaller jobs when they are complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can send the results back to first app and use an [aggregator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).

Comment: how would can you aggregate from different consumers?

Comment: You just need some kind of correlation and release strategy. The default correlation strategy uses the `correlationId` header. If you have a known number of consumers, you could use the default `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` which uses the sequence* headers.